# events vs reference sharing

Tags: java, javascript, php

Suppose I have a `TabManager` class which holds `tabs` array. There is also a controller that needs to track this `tabs` property and draw tabs in the array. I have two approaches to sharing this data:

First approach is reference sharing:

```
controller.tabs = tabManager.tabs
```

There are also many variations of the statement above, for example, this one:

```
// getTabs() returns reference to private _tabs property
controller.tabs = tabManager.getTabs();
```

Second approach is to notify controller when tabs array changes:

```
tabManager.on("tabSetChange", function(tabs) {
   // tabs here are clone of tabManager.tabs, not the same reference
   // so modifying controller.tabs won't affect tabManager.tabs
   controller.tabs = tabs;
});
```

Is there are a some rule of a thumb to decide which approach to choose? Lately, I'm inclined to use second approach to prevent accidental data change and with this approach debugging seems easier. But the second approach is also much more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like `TabManager` "owns" the tabs array and is responsible for making changes to it. The `controller` just needs a read-only view of the information in order to draw the tabs.

Presumably the `controller` needs to know when the tabs array changes such that the view needs to be refreshed. Simply sharing the reference doesn't give `controller` the ability to know when the array has changed, the TabManager would have to notify it. This leads to the event driven model you suggest being the better fit.

The event driven model allows the TabManager to emit events when there are relevant changes to the array, and for anyone who cares to be notified. This decoupling of components is a good thing. You may find another component wants to track the tabs array as well, so rather than hardcode a relationship to TabManager, it just registers an event listener.

This event based model is very much the JavaScript way.

Comment: Thanks! The controller doesn't need to know that the data is updated, it just needs to obtain new data. This is common inside `AngularJs` framework where a service holds some data and controller is used to draw that data.